# Kill process on Android by pid

Tags: java, android, linux

I found the some similar questions around stackoverflow, but I haven't found
one that works in my case.

So far, I tried:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","kill -9 "+pid});
    //am.killBackgroundProcesses(pkgName);
    //android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

While if I typed `su -c kill -9 pid` from **adb**, it worked! Why not work programmatically?

Do I need to put any `permission` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Btw, the device has been rooted.

Comment: What about this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380781/to-use-sudo-feature-what-should-i-wrote-in-the-my-application

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it's probably not a good idea to call `su` in this way. (every variation of pid will likely need to be authorized by whatever app is managing your calls to `su`) Most people call `sh` and then write the command they want to execute.

<strike>The error I noticed immediately is that your `-9` needs to be in a different part of the array. For example:</strike>

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "kill", "-9", ""+pid});
```

**Edit:** Actually, it seems like this should work. I forgot that the argument to `-c` needs to be the entire command.

You can find some example code [here](https://code.google.com/p/roottools/source/browse/trunk/Stable/RootTools-sdk3-generic/src/com/stericson/RootTools/execution/Executer.java) for executing a command as root on Android.

Another thing you can do is try specifying the full path to the `su` and `kill` binaries. (which may be phone-specific, so be careful)

**Edit 2:** I wonder if you're running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970217/). What version of Android are you using?

Comment: Do any exceptions occur? Did you check `adb logcat`?

Comment: The logcat didn't give any info about this